# Find duplicates among nested df

Tags: r

I have a data frame like so:

```
df<- data.frame(region= c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3", "4", 
"4"), 
 loc=c("1A","1A","1B","1C","2A","2B","2C","3A","3B","4A","4B"), sp1= 
c("a","a","b","a","c","c","c","a","a","d","d"), sp2= 
c("b","b","c","b","d","d","d","b","b", "e","e"), inter= 
c("a_b","a_b","b_c","a_b","c_d","c_d","c_d","a_b","a_b", 
"d_e","d_e"))
```

I would like to first subset `df` by region and find duplicate `inter` WITHIN each `region`. Then I would like to find duplicate `inter` AMONG  all regions. The first subset would look like:

```
subset1<- data.frame(region=c("1","2","3","4"), sp1= c("a", "c", "a", 
"d"),sp2= c("b", "d", "b", "e"), inter= c("a_b", "c_d", "a_b", 
"d_e"))
```

And the final output would look like:

```
df<- data.frame(sp1= c("a"), sp2= c("b"), inter=c("a_b"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this ( just need to drop some columns to meet your goal): 

#1
df=df%>%group_by(region,inter)%>%dplyr::mutate(n=n())%>%filter(row_number()==n()&n>1)

> df
Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
Groups: region, inter [4]

  region    loc    sp1    sp2  inter     n
  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <int>
1      1     1C      a      b    a_b     3
2      2     2C      c      d    c_d     3
3      3     3B      a      b    a_b     2
4      4     4B      d      e    d_e     2
#2
df%>%group_by(inter)%>%dplyr::mutate(n=n())%>%filter(row_number()==n()&n>1)

Source: local data frame [1 x 6]
Groups: inter [1]

  region    loc    sp1    sp2  inter     n
  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <int>
1      3     3B      a      b    a_b     2
```

Comment: You don't need the `mutate` step unless you want to add the counts to the dataset.  You can use `n() > 1` in `filter` directly without making an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 0):

For the duplicates within each region: Using `dplyr`, `filter` to duplicates within region, and then find `distinct` region-inter combinations:

```
library(dplyr)

within_region <- df %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  filter(duplicated(inter)) %>%
  distinct(region, inter, .keep_all = TRUE)

#   region    loc    sp1    sp2  inter
# 1      1     1A      a      b    a_b
# 2      2     2B      c      d    c_d
# 3      3     3B      a      b    a_b
# 4      4     4B      d      e    d_e
```

For a count of `inter` duplicates among all regions:

```
all_region <- df %>%
  count(inter)

#    inter     n
# 1    a_b     5
# 2    b_c     1
# 3    c_d     3
# 4    d_e     2
```